# Merge rows based on condtion

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data Frame like below

[image]

And I want merge "**Transaction Particulars**" index of 24,25 and 26 on index of 25 ,
same as  merge **Transaction Particulars** index of 28,29 and 30 on index of 29
And this merge based on **Tran Date** if Above and below value of **Tran Date**  is Nan then merge all this three index on **Tran Date** value index

i try with

```
tm['originalIdx'] = tm.apply(lambda x:x.name if x['Tran Date']!='' else None, axis=1).ffill()

tm = pd.merge(tm.drop('Transaction Particulars', axis=1),
            pd.DataFrame(tm.groupby(['originalIdx'])['Transaction Particulars'].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x))),
            left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')
```

Comment: [Dont post images of your data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: ya i will delete it @Erfan

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer

```
tm = tm[~tm['Tran Date'].str.match(r'^\D', na=False)].replace(np.nan,'')

tm['originalIdx'] = tm.apply(lambda x:x.name if x['Tran Date']!='' else None, axis=1).bfill(limit=1).ffill(limit=2)

tm = pd.merge(tm.drop('Transaction Particulars', axis=1), 
    pd.DataFrame(tm.groupby(['originalIdx'])['Transaction Particulars'].apply(lambda x: " ".join(str(v) for v in x))),
    left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')
```

using this code i solved my problem